# Handling math errors in C

Tags: c, error-handling, numeric

I would like to implement a numerical algorithm in C and I am having some issues regarding error handling. I use the `ldexp` function from `cmath.h` in a similar fashion as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ldexp/). Note that this (and the next example are from a C++ site. This is due to the fact that I was not able to find any up-to-date C-specific sites).

However, the `ldexp` function can overflow for a large exponent (the value of `n` in the example), in which case `inf` is returned.

I would like to ensure (at least in debug mode), that this error is detected.
I found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/math_errhandling/) example regarding C error handling, which raises even more question.

Firstly, there seem to be two different approaches of error handling: `MATH_ERREXCEPT` and `MATH_ERRNO`. On my system, both seem to be supported (according to the bitflag).

Why are there two different approaches?  Is one (or are both) of them standardized (in C11)? Can I make assumptions regarding which approach is used or do I always need to write code for both ones?

For each of the approaches: Do I need to clear the error state before executing an operation? What if I execute a series of `ldexp` operations and I am only interested in whether an error occurred in any operation (is it sufficient to check for an error once)?

Comment: It's probably worth you reading section "7.12.1 Treatment of error conditions" in [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) in fact the whole of section "7.12 Mathematics".

Comment: "I was not able to find any up-to-date C-specific sites" ... try [posix 1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) or [posix `ldexp()` specifically](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ldexp.html)

Comment: I recommend disabling the braindamage that is math functions setting `errno`, because it impedes the compiler generating efficient code. In gcc, use `-fno-math-errno`.

Comment: Do you need more than `double y = ldexp(x,n); if (!isfinite(y) Handle_Error();`?